# Sqlite / SQLAlchemy: how to enforce Foreign Keys?

Tags: python, sqlite, foreign-keys, sqlalchemy

The new version of SQLite has the ability to enforce Foreign Key constraints, but for the sake of backwards-compatibility, you have to turn it on for each database connection separately!

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

I am using SQLAlchemy -- how can I make sure this always gets turned on?
What I have tried is this:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
engine.execute('pragma foreign_keys=on')
```

...but it is not working!...What am I missing?

**EDIT:**
I think my real problem is that I have more than one version of SQLite installed, and Python is not using the latest one!

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> print sqlite3.sqlite_version
3.3.4
```

But I just downloaded 3.6.23 and put the exe in my project directory!
How can I figure out which .exe it's using, and change it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I now have this working:

Download the latest sqlite and pysqlite2 builds as described above: make sure correct versions are being used at runtime by python.

```
import sqlite3   
import pysqlite2 
print sqlite3.sqlite_version   # should be 3.6.23.1
print pysqlite2.__path__       # eg C:\\Python26\\lib\\site-packages\\pysqlite2
```

Next add a PoolListener:

```
from sqlalchemy.interfaces import PoolListener
class ForeignKeysListener(PoolListener):
    def connect(self, dbapi_con, con_record):
        db_cursor = dbapi_con.execute('pragma foreign_keys=ON')

engine = create_engine(database_url, listeners=[ForeignKeysListener()])
```

Then be careful how you test if foreign keys are working: I had some confusion here. When using sqlalchemy ORM to `add()` things my import code was implicitly handling the relation hookups so could never fail. Adding `nullable=False` to some `ForeignKey()` statements helped me here.

The way I test sqlalchemy sqlite foreign key support is enabled is to do a manual insert from a declarative ORM class:

```
# example
ins = Coverage.__table__.insert().values(id = 99,
                                    description = 'Wrong',
                                    area = 42.0,
                                    wall_id = 99,  # invalid fkey id
                                    type_id = 99)  # invalid fkey_id
session.execute(ins)
```

Here `wall_id` and `type_id` are both `ForeignKey()`'s and sqlite throws an exception correctly now if trying to hookup invalid fkeys. So it works! If you remove the listener then sqlalchemy will happily add invalid entries.

I believe the main problem may be multiple sqlite3.dll's (or .so) lying around.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working too.
Indeed, the problem was multiple copies of SQLite on my machine...fixing that, and using the PoolListener have worked perfectly!

Answer (score 60):

For recent versions (SQLAlchemy ~0.7) the [SQLAlchemy homepage](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/interfaces.html?highlight=poollistener#sqlalchemy.interfaces.PoolListener) says:

> PoolListener is deprecated. Please refer to [PoolEvents](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.PoolEvents).

Then the example by CarlS becomes:

```
engine = create_engine(database_url)

def _fk_pragma_on_connect(dbapi_con, con_record):
    dbapi_con.execute('pragma foreign_keys=ON')

from sqlalchemy import event
event.listen(engine, 'connect', _fk_pragma_on_connect)
```

Comment: conny's answer is perfect for newer versions of sqlalchemy. Use it! Moderator should really pick this one as correct.

Comment: Note this will throw an error when using different dialects. Use the answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15542046/4784914) to remain compatible with other dialects too.

Answer (score 55):

Building on the answers from conny and shadowmatter, here's code that will check if you are using SQLite3 before emitting the PRAGMA statement:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlite3 import Connection as SQLite3Connection

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def _set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    if isinstance(dbapi_connection, SQLite3Connection):
        cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;")
        cursor.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for those of us who prefer the `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` approach as well.

Comment: this also does the magic for `pandas.to_sql` as well, just copy it at the begining of the file that creates the session...

Comment: Thank you, this is the one to use.  The reply by @CarlS (which I appreciate is from 2010) uses stuff that has now been deprecated (looking at SQLAlchemy v1.3) and hence does not work anymore.

Answer (score 17):

As a simpler approach if your session creation is centralised behind a Python helper function (rather than exposing the SQLA engine directly), you can just issue `session.execute('pragma foreign_keys=on')` before returning the freshly created session.

You only need the pool listener approach if arbitrary parts of your application may create SQLA sessions against the database.

Comment: This is a good and easy solution when controlling your session with a @contextmanager.

Comment: If using Flask, you can call `db.session.execute('pragma foreign_keys=on')` before the queries in which you want FK constraint to be enforced. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 17):

From the [SQLite dialect page](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support):

> SQLite supports FOREIGN KEY syntax when emitting CREATE statements for tables, however by default these constraints have no effect on the operation of the table.
>
> Constraint checking on SQLite has three prerequisites:
>
> - At least version 3.6.19 of SQLite must be in use
> - The SQLite libary must be compiled without the SQLITE_OMIT_FOREIGN_KEY or SQLITE_OMIT_TRIGGER symbols enabled.
> - The PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON statement must be emitted on all connections before use.
>
> SQLAlchemy allows for the PRAGMA statement to be emitted automatically for new connections through the usage of events:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
    cursor.close()
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in a backend-agnostic way? I use SQLite3 for development but intend to use PostgreSQL for production. Is there a way to know whether to execute the pragma or not, i.e. to check if you've connected to a PostgreSQL or SQLite back-end?

Answer (score 7):

**One-liner** version of [conny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7831210/2111778):

```py
from sqlalchemy import event
```

```py
event.listen(engine, 'connect', lambda c, _: c.execute('pragma foreign_keys=on'))
```

Comment: YES. This works. Foreign key constraint is now properly enforced by sqlite. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem before (scripts with foreign keys constraints were going through but actuall constraints were not enforced by the sqlite engine); got it solved by:

1. downloading, building and installing the latest version of sqlite from here: [sqlite-sqlite-amalgamation](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-amalgamation-3.6.23.1.tar.gz); before this I had sqlite 3.6.16 on my ubuntu machine; which didn't support foreign keys yet; it should be 3.6.19 or higher to have them working.
2. installing the latest version of pysqlite from here: [pysqlite-2.6.0](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite/2.6.0)

after that I started getting exceptions whenever foreign key constraint failed

hope this helps, regards

Comment: I already have SQLite 3.6.23 and pysqlite 2.6.0 ( and new SQLAlchemy )
The SQLite doc says that you must explicitly turn on FK enforcement.
In your experience, when it did enforce, did you use that PRAGMA thing?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to execute something for setup on every connection, use a [PoolListener](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/reference/sqlalchemy/interfaces.html#sqlalchemy.interfaces.PoolListener).

Comment: Thanks -- I tried the PoolListener, and it did allow me to execute the pragma for every database connection!  Perfect! ...except that the pragma still does not work!  The SQLite engine still does not enforce foreign keys!...I am still missing a piece of the puzzle.  Maybe it's because I am on Windows?  The SQLite docs say something about the "build options" that it was built with...but I just got the standard install for Windows...not sure if that matters?

Answer (score 1):

Enforce Foreign Key constraints for sqlite when using Flask + SQLAlchemy.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

def create_app(config: str=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    if config is None:
        app.config.from_pyfile('dev.py')
    else:
        logger.debug('Using %s as configuration', config)
        app.config.from_pyfile(config)

    db.init_app(app)

    # Ensure FOREIGN KEY for sqlite3
    if 'sqlite' in app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']:
        def _fk_pragma_on_connect(dbapi_con, con_record):  # noqa
            dbapi_con.execute('pragma foreign_keys=ON')

        with app.app_context():
            from sqlalchemy import event
            event.listen(db.engine, 'connect', _fk_pragma_on_connect)
```

Source:
https://gist.github.com/asyd/a7aadcf07a66035ac15d284aef10d458