# Utf-8 with sqlalchemy on a database with init connect

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use sqlalchemy to connect with mysql database. I have set up `charset=utf-8$use_unicode=0`. This worked with almost all databases, but not with a particular one. I believe it is because it has 'init-connect' variable set to `'SET NAMES latin2;'` I have no privileges to change that.

It works for me if I send explicit query `SET NAMES utf8`, however if there is a temporal disconnection, then after reconnecting my program breaks again as it gets lati2-encoded data from the server.

Is it possible to create some hook to always send the `SET NAMES` when sqlalchemy connects? Or any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is a custom PoolListener. This SO answer explains how to write one in the context of SQLite's `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON`

[Sqlite / SQLAlchemy: how to enforce Foreign Keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614984/sqlite-sqlalchemy-how-to-enforce-foreign-keys/2615603#2615603)