# How to set SQLite PRAGMA statements with SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlite, sqlalchemy

I would like SQLAlchemy to put the SQLite .journal file in-memory to speed up performance.  I have tried this:

```
sqlite_db_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///%s' % str(dbname), connect_args = {'PRAGMA     journal_mode':'MEMORY', 'PRAGMA synchronous':'OFF', 'PRAGMA temp_store':'MEMORY', 'PRAGMA cache_size':'5000000'})

db = sqlite_db_engine.connect()
```

and this:

```
sqlite_db_engine = create_engine('sqlite:///%s' % str(dbname))

db = sqlite_db_engine.connect()
db.execute("PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY")
db.execute("PRAGMA synchronous = OFF")
db.execute("PRAGMA temp_store = MEMORY")
db.execute("PRAGMA cache_size = 500000")
```

With no luck.  For long transactions I can still see the .journal file being created on the disk.  Is there another way to set this?

*note I have no problem doing it with the built-in python sqlite module

Comment: I also tried to add a listener like this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614984/sqlite-sqlalchemy-how-to-enforce-foreign-keys

Comment: I got the error `DBAPIError: (TypeError) 'PRAGMA cache_size' is an invalid keyword argument for this function None None` when I try to user your code. This same error you got?

Comment: I don't get any errors, the code executes fine but apparently does nothing.

Answer (score 17):

How about using events:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL")
    cursor.close()
```

See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support

Comment: Is there a way to register different listeners depending on the target database (e.g. SQLite3 vs MySQL vs PostgreSQL) or to at least tell them apart after you're inside the listener's body (i.e. a way to programmatically check for this?

Comment: How can this be used in sqlalchemy though?

Comment: Any explanation as to why this works better than the simpler code provided by OP? Why are events required?

Comment: @code_dredd I found that this seems to work: `if isinstance(dbapi_connection, sqlite3.Connection):`

Comment: @wessel That might work, but it's not registering an event listener. You can also write `if not 'sqlite' in current_app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']: return`, but again, this isn't registering an event listener for that particular DB backend. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 10):

Basically you should be able to rewrite the examples about foreignkey to achieve what you want. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7831210/1890086

```
engine = create_engine(database_url)

def _fk_pragma_on_connect(dbapi_con, con_record):
    dbapi_con.execute('PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY')
    # ...

from sqlalchemy import event
event.listen(engine, 'connect', _fk_pragma_on_connect)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two previous solutions did not work, so I have found [the another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614984/sqlite-sqlalchemy-how-to-enforce-foreign-keys/2615603#2615603).

```
from sqlalchemy.interfaces import PoolListener
class MyListener(PoolListener):
    def connect(self, dbapi_con, con_record):
        dbapi_con.execute('pragma journal_mode=OFF')
        dbapi_con.execute('PRAGMA synchronous=OFF')
        dbapi_con.execute('PRAGMA cache_size=100000')

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///' + basefile,echo=False, listeners= [MyListener()])
```

Comment: In recent versions this will give: SADeprecationWarning: The 'listeners' argument to Pool (and create_engine()) is deprecated.  Use event.listen()