# sqlalchemy does not enforce foreign key constraing

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to play with the sql alchemy ORM based db definition.
I have defined my tables as follows

```
class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'

    id   = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(80))

    auth   = relationship("CustomerAuth", backref='customer')



class CustomerAuth(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'authentication'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('customer.id'))
    username = Column(String(80), primary_key=True)
    passwd = Column(String(80))
```

Now I am creating the session

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=sqla.engine)
session = Session()
```

And then I try to create two row objects for Customer with id 1 and 2

```
cst1 = sqla.Customer(id=1,name='shyam')
cst2 = sqla.Customer(id=2,name='ram')
```

And I create three row objects for CustomerAuth which reference to id 1, 2 and 3 of Customer

```
auth1 = sqla.CustomerAuth(id=1,username='shyamu',passwd='wam')
auth2 = sqla.CustomerAuth(id=2,username='ramu',passwd='dam')
auth3 = sqla.CustomerAuth(id=3,username='lamu',passwd='sam')
```

As you can see I have created a CustomerAuth row with id = 3 , which is a foreign key referring the Customer.id. But since Customer table has no entry with id=3 , this should fail

```
session.add(cst1)
session.add(cst2)
session.add(auth1)
session.add(auth2)
session.flush()
```

This operation should fail but it goes through successfully.

```
session.add(auth3)
session.flush()
```

I want to know what am I not doing which bypasses the foreign key enforcement

Thanks in advance

Comment: What RSBMS are you using? MySQL with MyISAM tables?

Comment: i am using sqlite. I am creating an in memory sqlite db as follows -----   from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)

Answer (score 3):

SQLite is responsible for enforcing constraints, not SQLAlchemy. For backwards compatibility reasons, SQLite requires a special parameter to enable the enforcement of foreign key. See the answers to this question: [Sqlite / SQLAlchemy: how to enforce Foreign Keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614984/sqlite-sqlalchemy-how-to-enforce-foreign-keys?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

As I found out and as pointed by @jd above the problem might be with sqlite. I changed my DB engine to mysql and its works fine as expected. So my apologies to sqlalchemy fans as I directly pointed fingers at sqlalchemy. :-)