# Flask Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: python, flask, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an issue with foreign key in Flask.
My model is the following :

**Model.py**

```
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "users"
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    user_id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    # EDIT
    alerts = db.relationship('Alert', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, user_id):
        self.user_id = user_id


class Alert(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'alert'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    alert_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('users.user_id'), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(ALERT_NAME_MAX_SIZE), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, user_id, name):
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.name = name
```

I am able to add some user, for example

```
a = User(16)
b = User(17)
db.session.add(a)
db.session.add(b)
db.session.commit()
```

and some alerts :

```
c = Alert(16, 'test')
d = Alert(17, 'name_test')
db.session.add(c)
db.session.add(d)
db.session.commit()
```

I have two issues with the foreign key : 
First of all, when I try to modify the user_id alert, I am able to do it even if the user_id is not in the database

```
 alert = Alert.query.get(1)
 alert.user_id = 1222 # not in the database
 db.session.commit()
```

and I am able to create a alert with an user_id not in the Database:

```
r = Alert(16223, 'test')
db.session.add(r)
```

I don't understand why they is no relationship constraint.
Thx,

Comment: Are you using sqlite ?

Comment: I am using SQLAlchemy

Comment: Yeah I can see that, but what's your database ? SQLite doesn't enforce foreign keys by default, you have to use specific config to get it working with SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Yes, but i don't find the good document ( or tuto ) about it

Comment: I try with db.ForeignKeyConstraint ( edit in my code) but no change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I find how to do it with [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614984/sqlite-sqlalchemy-how-to-enforce-foreign-keys) , I find how to force foreign Key Constraint.

I juste add this in  `__init__.py` and change nothing to  `models.py`

```
@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
    def _set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
         if isinstance(dbapi_connection, SQLite3Connection):
              cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
              cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;")
              cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is mistake in your code for initialisation of Alert class. You should use backref variable (which is 'user') instead of user_id while initializing Alert. Following code should work.

```
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "user"
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    user_id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    alerts = db.relationship('Alert', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, user_id):
        self.user_id = user_id


class Alert(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'alert'
    alert_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey('user.user_id'), nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String(ALERT_NAME_MAX_SIZE), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, user, name):
        self.user = user
        self.name = name
```

It works as below:

```
>>> a = User(7)
>>> db.session.add(a)
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> b = Alert(a, 'test')
>>> db.session.add(b)
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> alert = Alert.query.get(1)
>>> alert.user_id
7
>>> alert.user
<app.User object at 0x1045cb910>
>>> alert.user.user_id
7
```

It does not allow you to assign variable like `d = Alert(88, 'trdft')`

I think you should read [Flask SqlAlchemy's One-to-Many Relationships](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/models/#one-to-many-relationships) for more details.

Comment: Doesn't work, i can still create alert with no-existing user_id and modify an alerte with a no-existing user_id

Comment: Hello, Thx but it still don't work, i am able to create `d = Alert(88, 'trdft')`even if 88 is not in the user db

Comment: It should work. Alert(88, 'trdft') should throw an error because Alert is expecting (<object of User class>, <string>) while initialization. 88 is not object of User class, it is an integer so it should throw error. Are you sure you changed arguments passing to `__init__` of Alert class? You should use same variable as backref variable i.e. if you have `alerts = db.relationship('Alert', backref='random_var', lazy='dynamic')` in `User` class then `__init__` of Alert will look like `def __init__(self, random_var, name)`.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, i didn't change `__init__` but now I have a different issue. I cannot add a alert with an existing User..... I can add a alert with an new User, and the User will be create. When I try to create a alert with an existing User I got :  `IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: users.user_id `

Comment: Did you start with fresh db? I have made small change in my answer. I had changed tablename to 'user' but forgot to change it in foreignkey declaration `db.ForeignKey('user.user_id')` before. Now it should work perfectly. If not, could you give your code and exact error by editing the question? And try with fresh db. Thanks.

Comment: Great explanation +1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQLite, foreign key constraints are by default not enforced. See [Enabling Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable) in the documentation for how to enable this.