# Foreign key contraint is not getting set in SQLlite using flask alchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlite, session, sqlalchemy

I have below table schema defined in sqlalchemy where user_id is foreign key referencing to User's user_id table

```
class Manufacturer(Model):
__tablename__='Manufacturer'
Manufacturer_id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True,autoincrement=True)
name=Column(String(length=100),nullable=False)
description=Column(String(length=1000),nullable=False)
user_id=Column(Integer,ForeignKey(User.user_id),nullable=False)
```

but when table is created in sqllite db foreign key not added to table and entry is getting inserted even though user table does not have value for userid

i searched for this issue and found in order to solve this problem we need to set 
`PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;`
but i am not able to figure it out how this can be done with my current configuration for DB

i have below code to create engine and to add record with SQL
Configuration for engine :-

`engine=create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
_Session=orm.sessionmaker(autocommit=False,autoflush=True,bind=engine)
session=orm.scoped_session(_Session)`

code to add entry in table

```
 man_details=Manufacturer(**param)
    session.add(man_details)
    session.commit()
```

Please suggest how i can set foreign key constraint from python-Flask-SQLAlchemy for tables created in SQLlite3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code worked for me and found it from below link -

[Sqlite / SQLAlchemy: how to enforce Foreign Keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614984/sqlite-sqlalchemy-how-to-enforce-foreign-keys)

```
   def _fk_pragma_on_connect(dbapi_con, con_record):
    dbapi_con.execute('pragma foreign_keys=ON')

from sqlalchemy import event
event.listen(engine, 'connect', _fk_pragma_on_connect)
```