# Foreign keys doesn't work well with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new in Flask and especially with SQLAlchemy concept. I have two models which call User and Message:

```py
@dataclass
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id: int
    email: str
    password: str
    name: str

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(100), unique=True)
    password = Column(String(100))
    name = Column(String(100))


@dataclass
class Message(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'message'
    id: int
    sender: int
    receiver: int
    message: str
    creation_date: datetime
    did_read: bool


    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    sender = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    receiver = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    message = Column(String(200), nullable=False)
    creation_date = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    did_read = Column(Boolean, default=False)
```

`sender` and `receiver` in `Message` model should hold the `id` of a correct user.
And, for example, when I try to send a messege from user with `id=1` (which is in the database) to user with `id=2` (**which is not in the database yet)** it allows me to send it anyway and is not make sense since user with `id=2` is not in the database.
I want that it will raise an error and notify me that the user doesn't exist.
What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: What database are you using? I think SqlAlchemy depends on the database to enforce this constraint.

Comment: If you're using SQLite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614984/sqlite-sqlalchemy-how-to-enforce-foreign-keys

Comment: what meas `send` ? Do you have some function to send message ? How do you use database for sending message? Maybe problem is this function, not in database.