# Foreign key value for non-existent parent?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I´m trying to create some tree type hierarchy data structure using sqlalchemy, and closure table strategy.

The idea is to build very basic hierarchy behaviour and then derive the _vNode class to specialize it with more attributes.

```
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, Session

class _vBase(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class _vNode(_vBase):
    __tablename__ = "vNode"

    id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    type: Mapped[str]
    
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "base_vNode",
        "polymorphic_on": "type",
    }

class _vLink(_vBase):
    __tablename__ = "base_link"

    parent_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(_vNode.id), nullable=True,)
    parent = relationship(_vNode, foreign_keys=[parent_id])
    
    child_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(ForeignKey(_vNode.id), primary_key=True)
    child = relationship(_vNode, foreign_keys=[child_id])
    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['parent_id', 'child_id'],
            ['vNode.id', 'vNode.id']
        ),
    )
```

It works OK, but when I create a _vLink with a parent_id that does not exist on the _vNode table, I was expecting an exception, but it works fine.

```
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, Session
from sqlalchemy.schema import ForeignKeyConstraint
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, sessionmaker

file = 'test_tree.db'
url = f'sqlite:///{file}'

engine = create_engine(url)
_vBase.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

#add a Node with parent_id=None works ok
node1 = _vNode(id="node1")
link1 = _vLink(parent_id=None, child_id=node1.id)
session.add(node1)
session.add(link1)
session.commit()

#add a Node with a parent_id="unexistent_id" should raise an exception in my concept, but it does not
node2 = _vNode(id="node2")
link2 = _vLink(parent_id="unexistent_id", child_id=node2.id)
session.add(node2)
session.add(link2)
session.commit()
```

I even tried to add ForeignKeyConstrains to the _vLink, but didn´t help

What am I missing ???

Comment: have you tried enabling the foreign key? https://stackoverflow.com/q/2614984/12502959

Comment: I´ve just tried to do as "conny" answer. It works, but It break when parent_id is null... So, I would need to relax this constrains when parent_id is null. Any idea on how to do it ?

Comment: At least for debugging purposes, try commenting out the `__table_args__` now that you have FKs enabled in SQLite. Does that work better with a null parent_id?

Comment: No change when "__table_args__" is commented out. I´m using a work around checking the existence of the parent_id by query, but would like to get the db doing it itself.

Comment: What's unclear at this point is whether your issue is with a parent_id that is null (None) or with a parent_id that is non-null but simply does not exist in the vNode table. Please [edit] your question to clearly show what you are currently asking about. Include complete error messages, expected vs. actual behaviour, etc..